# How to use ffmpeg to separate video and audio file name for dash segment?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to define m4a for audio and m4v for video in dash segment.

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i out_dash.mp4 -c copy -f dash -window_size 5 \
  -min_seg_duration 500 -single_file 1 \
  -init_seg_name initavatar-stream\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$ \
  -media_seg_name chunk-stream\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$ \
  -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1  index.mpd
```

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: ffmpeg does not accept variables unless you are using it in a script.

Comment: for ffmpeg document , it support this variables depends the templete, but i try many times. it doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" is not descriptive, so I don't know what the actual issue is.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it clearly， i mean many variables can take effect such as $RepresentationID, but $ext can not be changed to m4v or m4a.

Comment: This is a problem with your scripting language, not with ffmpeg.